# Attempt to reassemble RAID 1 on Linux; accidentally created new /dev/md0 (instead of reassemble) and now it won’t mount

Tags: linux, raid1

I was attempting to reassemble a working RAID 1 array, and I accidentally did a `mdadm --create` instead of `mdadm --assemble`, and now the RAID device won't mount.

Mistake:  at first I unfortunately did:

```
$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

After that, attempts to mount `/dev/md0` fail:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/mirror
mount: /mnt/mirror: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Now, when I try to do the `--assemble`, the RAID device will not mount:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is busy - skipping
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 2 drives.
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/mirror
mount: /mnt/mirror: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How do I get the fs type back to the proper setting for RAID 1 (without formatting! – I don't want to destroy the data!)

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 409bb846:c04ba3d6:cff546fe:b63ce279
           Name : mojo:0  (local to host mojo)
  Creation Time : Sat Jun  1 14:40:46 2019
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 977008640 (465.87 GiB 500.23 GB)
     Array Size : 488253440 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976506880 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=501760 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 36202ff4:4c450b4c:4e45f049:83d16385

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jun  1 16:38:50 2019
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 19e7023e - correct
         Events : 719


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      488253440 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [==================>..]  resync = 94.0% (459229248/488253440) finish=7.0min speed=68932K/sec
      bitmap: 1/4 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72105
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x69ed0c28

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 976773167 976771120 465.8G fd Linux raid autodetect
```

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="409bb846-c04b-a3d6-cff5-46feb63ce279" UUID_SUB="36202ff4-4c45-0b4c-4e45-f04983d16385" LABEL="mojo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0004e809-01"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="409bb846-c04b-a3d6-cff5-46feb63ce279" UUID_SUB="63ec26cb-7468-8e16-1e32-08e984d3245d" LABEL="mojo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="69ed0c28-01"

sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/mirror
mount: /mnt/mirror: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
sudo blkid /dev/md0

No output from blkid on /dev/md0.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the fdisk output there.

Comment: Attempted to add fdisk output, but formatting got crunched.  It lists the Disklabel type as 'dos'.

Comment: Is there actually a filesystem on `/dev/md0`? Add the output of `blkid` to your question.

Comment: Nasir -- yes, /dev/md0 was a working raid 1 device for several years.  It was ext4.

Comment: $ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="409bb846-c04b-a3d6-cff5-46feb63ce279" UUID_SUB="36202ff4-4c45-0b4c-4e45-f04983d16385" LABEL="mojo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0004e809-01"                                                                       
/dev/sdc1: UUID="409bb846-c04b-a3d6-cff5-46feb63ce279" UUID_SUB="63ec26cb-7468-8e16-1e32-08e984d3245d" LABEL="mojo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="69ed0c28-01"

Comment: @jsotola: Please don’t add the word “edit” to a post to delimit an edit.

Comment: @JamesRisinger Just add the output of `blkid`. We're trying to see if there is a filesystem on that RAID array itself, not the disks making it up. If you're going to specify a device, use `blkid /dev/md0` as that will show if there is a filesystem on the RAID array. Add it to your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: @NasirRiley Ok, added the blkid of /dev/md0.  There is no output for that command.

Comment: If `/dev/md0` isn't even showing up in `blkid` then not only is there not a filesystem on it, something went wrong when you created it. It's not going to mount without a filesystem but that should be the least of your worries at this point. Is the data backed up?

Comment: @roaima That was my mistake in the original post -- fixed it.  Should read: $ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1

Comment: @NasirRiley You're right, /dev/md0 is definitely in a fouled state at this point.  These two drives were used for a long time as raid 1 w/ ext4.  My *big mistake* was to do mdadm --create instead of mdadm --assemble.  My online searching has found many posts from folks who made a similar error -- however I could find no solution.  So the basic problem is how to set the superblocks for the two devices back to something that makes sense, or possibly mount the ext4 fs directly (since they're mirrored.) to undo my error.  Not worried about the data at this point, just want to see if can be fixed.